# How do I call an array outside of a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that display and hide elements on a page. I'm trying to make the code more efficient so if elements get added to the page I don't have to update every line. This is how the code is now:

```
function myOpenFunction() {
   var elem1 = document.getElementById("div1");
   if (elem1) { document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";}
   var elem2 = document.getElementById("div2");
   if (elem2) { document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";}
   var elem3 = document.getElementById("div3");
   if (elem3) { document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "table";}
}


function myCloseFunction() {
   var elem1 = document.getElementById("div1");
   if (elem1) { document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";}
   var elem2 = document.getElementById("div2");
   if (elem2) { document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";}
   var elem3 = document.getElementById("div3");
   if (elem3) { document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";}
}
```

I tried putting all of those variables into an array outside of the function so that I don't have to repeat the variables if I add new elements. However, it doesn't work.

```
var myArray = [
document.getElementById("div1"), 
document.getElementById("div2"),
document.getElementById("div3")
];

function myOpenFunction() {
   if (myArray[0]) { myArray[0].style.display = "block";}
   if (myArray[1]) { myArray[1].style.display = "block";}
   if (myArray[2]) { myArray[2].style.display = "table";}
}

function myCloseFunction() {
   if (myArray[0]) { myArray[0].style.display = "none";}
   if (myArray[1]) { myArray[1].style.display = "none";}
   if (myArray[2]) { myArray[2].style.display = "none";}
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: When declaring an array, array items need to be separated by *commas*, not semicolons.

Comment: Could you not have a class set on every element that needs affecting (show/hide) and then you don't have hard coded id1, id2, id3, ... , id# that is ever expanding? Just find all divs with the class and loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myOpenFunction` and `myCloseFunction`s are checking whether the elements exist *at the time the function is called*, whereas your `myArray` is putting the elements into the array *when the script runs* - the logic is not the same. You might use an array of ids, and then when the open or close function is called, iterate over the array to call `getElementById` to extract each element, and if it exists, set its `style`:

```
const ids = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3'];
function myOpenFunction() {
  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
      element.style.display =
      i === 2
      ? 'block'
      : 'table';
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a counter and concatenate with your class names to push to your array. You just need to have all your divs with IDs of `div1`, `div2`, etc:

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("selectedDivs");
var myArray = [];

for (var i = 1; I <= myElements.length; i++) {
    myArray.push("div" + i);
}
```

Then use this in your function:

```
if (document.getElementById(myArray[I]) {
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give all items the same class and loop other them. If you need different display states for some elements, you could specify them inside an html data attribute.

```js
const myElements = document.querySelectorAll('.open-close');

function myOpenFunction() {
  myElements.forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.display = elem.dataset.display || 'block';
  });
}


function myCloseFunction() {
   myElements.forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="open-close">...</div>
<div class="open-close">...</div>
<div class="open-close" data-display="table">...</div>
```

EDIT: Because I am not shure about your JavaScript experience, here is a maybe more simple version with more classic methods and syntax:

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName('open-close');

function myOpenFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
        var elem = myElements[i];
        var displayAttr = elem.getAttribute('data-display');
        if (displayAttr !== null) {
            elem.style.display = displayAttr;
        } else {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}

function myCloseFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
        myElements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```